# Android: Add a custom button to SearchView Widget in Actionbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-custom-view, android-button, searchview

I would like to add a custom button to SearchView widget.

Going through source code of `search_view` layout file I found out that it has a `LinearLayout` (`submit_area`) that contains submit button and voice button.

So I added a dynamic button to submit_area. But it doesn't show my dynamically added button because if either submit button or voice button is not enabled then `submit_area` is invisible. So it doesn't matter if I add anything dynamically.

```
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menuItem.getActionView(); 

int
submit_areaId = searchView.getContext().getResources()
    .getIdentifier("android:id/submit_area", null, null);

Button btnScan = new Button(getActivity());
btnScan.setText(getString(R.string.scan)); submitArea.addView(btnScan);
```

However if I just set submit button enabled then it shows submit button as well as my dynamic button, like in the attached photo.

I just want to show my dynamic button only. Any clue how to achieve that?

[image]

Comment: What is "submitArea" here in your code ,    submitArea.addView(btnScan);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since a private `SearchView` class method is setting `submit_area` `Visibility.Gone` so we can't do much about it.

A quick dirty trick is to set of the default buttons enabled and then set its width and height to 0. Setting `Visibility` didn't work so have to set height/width.

I enabled search button and then set its height/width to zero.

```
int submit_areaId = searchView.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/submit_area", null, null);

ImageView submitImage = (ImageView) searchView.findViewById(search_go_btnId);

searchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, 0);

submitImage.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Now SearchView will show anything that you add in submit_area.

Answer (score 5):

```
searchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(false);    
LinearLayout linearLayoutOfSearchView = (LinearLayout) searchView.getChildAt(0);
Button yourButton = new Button(mContext); // and do whatever to your button
linearLayoutOfSearchView.addView(yourButton);
```

Comment: Please add some decription to your answer to help the OP understand the solution

Comment: You missed the point in the question. Button is already added to the view. If you disable Submit/Voice buttons then View will not show at all. In my answer below is shows how to show custom button without disabling default button.